# Directive inside a Directive with transclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey Stackoverflow peep.

This works:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Data = {
      name: "Bob"
    }

  }).directive("formText", function() {
    return {
      template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="data" name="{{key}}" id="{{key}}"></div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
      label: "@label",
      key: "@key",
        data: "="
      }
    };
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ownmph09/4/

That fiddle works. You can change controller scope value. Pretty straight forward.

But this one does not:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.Data = {
      name: "Bob"
    }

  }).directive("formText", function() {
    return {
      template: '<div form-input label="{{label}}"><input type="text" ng-model="data" name="{{key}}" id="{{key}}"></div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
      label: "@label",
      key: "@key",
        data: "="
      }
    };
  }).directive('formInput', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{label}}</label><div class="col-sm-8" ng-transclude></div></div>',
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        label: "@label"
      }
    };
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ownmph09/3/

I'm sure it has to do with the transclude and isolated scopes but I don't quite understand what's going on. Hoping someone that knows this stuff better than me can help.